# tracked robot Gazebo-ROS

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, mobile, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, I'm trying to create a simulator in gazebo under ROS, for a robot base. This robot base has tracked wheels. I would like to ask you how to implement them in ros and Gazebo, in particular:

- is there any kind of specific transmission ?
- do I have to build the urdf xacro in a particular way ?
- is there any kind of example (I didn't find it from my own)?

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249874/tracked-robot-gazebo-ros/) by [almosca](https://answers.ros.org/users/22088/almosca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now there is official support for tracked robots in Gazebo 9 and 11 using ODE. Check out https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/worlds/tracked_vehicle_simple.world for usage example.

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2020-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-25**:
As this is now the answer, I've marked it as *the* answer instead of my earlier one.

**Comment by [pranshu](https://answers.ros.org/users/57399/pranshu/) on 2020-08-06**:
@gvdhoorn @peci1 Thank you for this solution. I was able to run the demo. But i am unable to implement the plugin on my robot design. Could anyone of you help me do it? I added the keyboardGUI and simple tracked vehicle plugin. But its not working in my case. My robot isn't moving. For a note, my robot design is in urdf xacro format

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2020-08-10**:
@pranshu It'd be best if you created a new question here where you post your whole Xacro file and the process you make an SDF from it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I gave a fully physical version of this a try in my bullet physics wrapper (https://github.com/lucasw/simple_sim_ros as opposed to Gazebo) and got okay results:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYB8zXb6O_I

[image: image description]

Obstacles much higher than the one shown in the video resulted in a lot of slipping when the back wheels reached it.

The tracks are driven like a gear with teeth meshing with the gaps between track plates, and inner and outer wheel covers with a slightly larger diameter than the inner wheel keeps the tracks from falling off.  Some cheating may be going on if the wheel covers or teeth are contacting the ground rather than than just the treads.

The whole thing shakes around a bit which may be a precursor to sim instability in rougher environments or with a different configuration.

It took around 20% cpu on a 2.8GHz i7, given that and additional mechanisms that ought to be added that would take up more cpu (like maybe a packbot style second set of treads on flippers, or a higher density of plates) it may not be worth it unless simulating tracks is important.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-08-06**:
I wish this answer came with the configuration files for this robot, that would just make it perfect.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-08-06**:
You should be able to launch it with the files in the github repo:

```
roslaunch bullet_server tracked_vehicle.launch
```

(Though I haven't tried it recently)

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-08-07**:
Nice, my bad, I didn't see that it was an example file :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not entirely sure, but afaik there is (still) no dedicated support for tracked vehicles in Gazebo. One approach/work-around I seem to remember is that people use skid-steering for the dynamics with a track-like appearance for visualisation.

All-in-all I believe you have a better chance of getting good answers over at `answers.gazebosim.org`, but some related questions / links:

- [Tracked vehicles simulation](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4369)
- [Simulating a track driven robot](http://answers.ros.org/question/10410)
- [Parameters for a skid steering/simulated tracked robot (use of the fdir1 tag)](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5476)
- [Problems in simulating a tracked vehicle and spawning the model](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6353)
- [osrf/gazebo/issues/863/tracksdriveplugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/863/tracksdriveplugin)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [almosca](https://answers.ros.org/users/22088/almosca/) on 2016-12-12**:
thanks a lot for the answer, i will have a look on these links !! :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-12**:
Did you cross-post to [tracked robot Gazebo-ROs](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14998)? Or was that after we referred you to that site?